# How do I run a Ruby Gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass

This might seem stupid, but I recently tried to install SASS and followed their instructions:

```
$ gem install sass 
$ sass --watch [...]
```

So I followed along:

```
root@server:~# gem install sass
Successfully installed sass-3.1.15
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sass-3.1.15...
Installing RDoc documentation for sass-3.1.15...

root@server:~# sass
bash: sass: command not found
```

Despite looking around like an idiot trying to find some simple way to run something like `gem run sass` or some other workaround to make it function, I am more or less at a loss.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin` (though the problem has been solved, see below). Thanks for putting it on the right track though :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that Debian/Ubuntu drops ruby gems into `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`.

So the solution (at least for Ubuntu/Debian) is:

```
$ sudo -s
# echo 'PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH' > /etc/profile.d/gemspath.sh
# chmod 0755 /etc/profile.d/gemspath.sh
```

...and then open a new shell session.

(This is fixed in [Ubuntu 11.10](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/r/rubygems/rubygems_1.7.2-1/changelog).)

Answer (score 7):

If you happen to have installed Ruby through [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), you'll need to execute the following command

> rbenv rehash

Comment: I had to also clean up the file `$HOME/.rbenv/shims/.rbenv-shim` to fix this. Posted your solution on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

On macOS I had to add the gem executable directory to the path.
Add these lines to your ~/.bashrc file, and reopen the terminal to refresh the env vars.

```
# gem                                                                      
gembin=`(gem env | sed -n "s/.*EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: \(.*\)/\1/p")`
export PATH=$gembin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use macOS and you:

- I don't know/care about Ruby.
- I just want to run this program.
- Why is this so complicated?

Then run:

`~/.gem/ruby/*/bin/jekyll`

where `jekyll` is the thing you just installed with `gem install`.

Comment: if using brew to install ruby the path of ruby gem will be at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/*/gems/gem-name/bin/executable-file-name

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using MacOS Sonoma M1 and installed Ruby 2.7 via Homebrew.

```
brew install ruby@2.7
```

Set the appropriate bin path in either .zshrc or .bashrc.

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@2.7/bin:/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin:$PATH"
```

You need to install the Ruby Gem.

```
gem install /path/to/<ruby-gem>.gem
```

You can then execute ruby gem.

```
<ruby-gem> -h
```

See the installation bin path of your ruby gem.

```
which <ruby-gem>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're trying to run a simple WEBrick server for your gem you can do the following after installation:

```sh
sass start
```