# How to correctly configure ruby gems on Debian 11.4?

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems

This is a follow-up to

[How do I run a Ruby Gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792803/how-do-i-run-a-ruby-gem)

Without much knowledge about ruby, I followed

https://linuxconfig.org/getting-started-with-jekyll-on-debian-9-stretch-linux

to install Jekyll. I did

```
# apt install build-essential ruby-full
# gem install bundler minima jekyll-feed
```

but then jekyll was not in PATH. I have found jekyll in

```
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/exe
```

I have put it into PATH and now I can start it with

```
$ jekyll -v
```

When I try

```
$ jekyll build
```

it complains about not finding other gems with

```
Bundler::GemNotFound
```

How can I systematically set the PATH for all gems?

Comment: have you thought about using `rvm` or `rbenv` rather than the provided operating system packages? you'll find a lot of the headache is solved for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use rbenv, I followed

https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/22.04

and it worked.